# dragStart event not initiating when mousedown outside of parent container (overflow: visible)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a UI tool utilising the [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) which allows users to mockup part of a website by dragging pre-prepared elements onto a grid layout:

[image]

It's pretty much there but there's a small issue. Once an element has been dragged onto the grid, that element can only be re-positioned when mousing down over the top left most part of the element (the dimensions of the parent container to be precise), the coordinates depicted in boxes 1 & 2 below:

[image]

When attempting to drag these elements from any area outside of the parent element, the dragStart event does not initiate.

Commenting out the following css fixes this issue but presents another...

```
/* comment out this code to see the issue */
.design-frame:has(.dragging) [id^="col-"]:not(:has(.dragging)) {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

This css allows the ability for dragged elements to be placed within grid squares which they also currently occupy (to allow users to nudge the element over a few spaces without having to remove and re-place it completely):

[image]

It does this by updating the stacking order of all adjacent grid squares so that they appear in front of the parent square containing the currently dragged element.

Without this css, the element can be dragged from any part of itself, but can no longer be dragged *within* itself, as the adjacent squares are no longer dominant in the stacking order.

It's quite an intuitive tool, give it a try and you'll see what I mean:
(you may need to go full page)

```js
const design = $('.design-frame');
const fragment = $(document.createDocumentFragment());

// Create the grid
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  const row = $(document.createElement('div'));
  row.attr('id', `row-${i + 1}`);
  fragment.append(row);
  for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    const col = $(document.createElement('div'));
    col.attr('id', `col-${j + 1}`);
    col.attr('data-role', 'drag-drop-container');
    row.append(col);
  }
}
design.append(fragment);

const items = $('.items-group');
const itemsData = [["gallery","6","4"],
                   ["brand","3","1"],
                   ["title","6","1"],
                   ["bullets","6","3"],
                   ["price","3","1"],
                   ["save","3","1"],
                   ["stock","2","1"],
                   ["icon","1","1"],
                   ["icon","1","1"],
                   ["icon","1","1"]];

// Create the items
for (let i = 0; i < itemsData.length; i++) {
  const [name, width, height] = itemsData[i];
  const itemContainer = $(document.createElement('div'));
  itemContainer.attr('id', `placeholder-${i + 1}`);
  itemContainer.addClass('placeholder');
  itemContainer.attr('data-role', 'drag-drop-container');

  const itemDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
  itemDiv.attr('id', `item-${i + 1}`);
  itemDiv.addClass('child-div');
  itemDiv.addClass(name);
  itemDiv.css('width', `${width*50}px`);
  itemDiv.css('height', `${height*50}px`);
  itemDiv.attr('data-style-width', width);
  itemDiv.attr('data-style-height', height);
  itemDiv.attr('draggable', true);

  const itemContent = $(document.createElement('span'));
  itemContent.attr('id', name);
  itemContent.text(name);

  itemDiv.append(itemContent);
  itemContainer.append(itemDiv);
  fragment.append(itemContainer);
}
items.append(fragment);

let sourceContainerId = "",
    currentDraggedWidth = "",
    currentDraggedHeight = "";

// Allow multiple draggable items
let dragSources = $('[draggable="true"]');
dragSources.each(function() {
  $(this).on("dragstart", dragStart);
  $(this).on("dragend", dragEnd);
});

function allowDrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragStart(e) {
  $(this).addClass("dragging");
  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);
  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
  sourceContainerId = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
  currentDraggedWidth = $(this).attr('data-style-width');
  currentDraggedHeight = $(this).attr('data-style-height');
}

function dragEnd(e) {
  $(this).removeClass("dragging");
}

// Allow multiple dropped targets
let dropTargets = $('[data-role="drag-drop-container"]');
dropTargets.each(function() {
  $(this).on("drop", dropped);
  $(this).on("dragenter", cancelDefault);
  $(this).on("dragover", dragOver);
  $(this).on("dragleave", dragLeave);
});

function dropped(e) {
  // execute function only when target container is different from source container
  if (this.id !== sourceContainerId) {
    cancelDefault(e);
    let id = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    if (this.childNodes.length == 0 ) {
      $("#" + id).appendTo($(this));
    } else {
      let child = $("#" + id);
      let parentId = "placeholder-" + id.split('-')[1];
      let parent = $("#" + parentId);

      if (parent.is(':empty')) {
        child.appendTo(parent);
      } else {
        child.appendTo($('.items-group >*:empty').first());
      }
    }
    removeHover();
  }
}

let timeout;

function debounce(func, delay) {
  return function() {
    const context = this;
    const args = arguments;

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay);
  };
}

function dragOver(e) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  cancelDefault(e);

  $(this).addClass('hover');
  if($(this).parents('.design-frame').length) {
    $(this).addClass('w-' + currentDraggedWidth + ' h-' + currentDraggedHeight);
  }
}

function dragLeave(e) {
  $(this).removeClass("hover");
  removeHover();
}

function cancelDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  removeHover();
  return false;
}

function removeHover() {
  $('[id^="col-"]').removeClass();
  $('[id^="placeholder-"]').removeClass();
}

function setAttributes(el, attrs) {    
  $.each(attrs, function(key, value) {
    $(el).attr(key, value);
  }); 
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: calc(100dvh - 1rem);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.workspace {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 4rem);
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.workspace >* {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.design-outer {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  outline: 4px solid transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .2s;
}

.design-outer:has(.hover) {
  outline: 4px solid lightblue;
}

.design-frame {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: 2px solid #fff;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

.design-frame:has(.dragging) .child-div {
  opacity: .75;
}

[draggable="true"] {
    /*
   To prevent user selecting inside the drag source
  */
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

.design-frame [id^="row-"] {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
}

.design-frame [id^="col-"] {
  user-select: none;
}

body:has(.dragging) [id^="col-"] {
  outline: 1px dashed lightgrey;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

[id^="col-"]:before {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

[id^="col-"].hover:before {
  content: '';
}

[id^="col-"]:not(:empty).hover:before {
  background-color: orange;
}

[id^="col-"].hover.w-1:before { width: 50px; }
[id^="col-"].hover.w-2:before { width: 100px; }
[id^="col-"].hover.w-3:before { width: 150px; }
[id^="col-"].hover.w-4:before { width: 200px; }
[id^="col-"].hover.w-5:before { width: 250px; }
[id^="col-"].hover.w-6:before { width: 300px; }

[id^="col-"].hover.h-1:before { height: 50px; }
[id^="col-"].hover.h-2:before { height: 100px; }
[id^="col-"].hover.h-3:before { height: 150px; }
[id^="col-"].hover.h-4:before { height: 200px; }
[id^="col-"].hover.h-5:before { height: 250px; }
[id^="col-"].hover.h-6:before { height: 300px; }

.items {
  max-width: 320px;
  justify-self: center;
}

.items-outer {
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: 4px solid transparent;
  transition: .2s;
}

.items-outer:has(.hover) {
  outline: 4px solid lightblue;
}

.items-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: .5rem;
  transform: scale(.75);
}

.items-group >* {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  transition: .2s;
}

.items-group >*:empty {
  --color: 233,233,233;
  outline: 1px dashed lightgrey;
  outline-offset: -1px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to top left,
      rgba(var(--color),0) 0%,
      rgba(var(--color),0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
      rgba(var(--color),1) 50%,
      rgba(var(--color),0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
      rgba(var(--color),0) 100%),
    linear-gradient(to top right,
      rgba(var(--color),0) 0%,
      rgba(var(--color),0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
      rgba(var(--color),1) 50%,
      rgba(var(--color),0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
      rgba(var(--color),0) 100%);
}

.items-group >*:empty.hover {
  background: none;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.items-group .child-div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  outline: none;
}

.child-div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: grey;
  outline: 2px solid #fff;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

.child-div span {
  padding: .5rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.child-div.gallery { 

}

.child-div:hover {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  cursor: move;
}

.child-div:hover:before {
  --color: grey;
  content: '.';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 14px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: var(--color);
  text-shadow: 0 5px var(--color), 0 10px var(--color), 5px 0 var(--color), 5px 5px var(--color), 5px 10px var(--color);
}

.child-div.dragging {
  opacity: .25;
}

.child-div.dragging:before {
  content: unset;
}


/* comment out this code to see the issue */
.design-frame:has(.dragging) [id^="col-"]:not(:has(.dragging)) {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="workspace" data-role="drag-drop-container">
    <div class="items">
      <div class="items-outer">
        <div class="items-group"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="design">
      <div class="design-outer">
        <div class="design-frame"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to achieve both desired outcomes?

1. Allow elements to be dragged from any part of itself.
2. Allow dragged elements to be placed within grid squares which they also currently occupy.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks, Mr. J